# jQuery width() and outerWidth() produce strange results

Tags: jquery, css

Can someone please explain why when the HTML is

```
<div class="div">This is a normal DIV</div>
```

the jQuery

```
$('.div').width("50%");

and

$('.div').outerWidth("50%");
```

produce such strange results? I have tried this with normally positioned DIVs, absolutely positioned DIVs, and with and without CSS

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

I am getting squished DIVs (ie. minimum width) with **outerWidth("50%")** when border-box is not set, and wider-than-expected DIVs with **width("50%")** when border-box is set. (FWIW, **position: absolute** appears to make no difference.)

See https://jsfiddle.net/zk1gys7z/1/

Comment: you should probably read about `border-box`

Comment: Looks like there may be a bug in jQuery: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1712

Answer (score 0):

I can't really explain what's going on there with JS, it doesn't always seem to be applying 50%, I saw styles applied that were 8%, 92% and other weird values.

I think you'll get the result you're looking for with:

```
$('.div').css("width", "50%");
```

With `border box` applied it will take the padding into account, without, it will size just the content to be 50% (the padding will be extra)

Comment: Thanks @Darvanen. For now I am using outerWidth() with border-box but this is very weird behaviour and I hope someone can still explain why it's happening.